# Reservation Used Bytes parameter keeps changing

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-monitoring, google-bi-engine

I created a dashboard in the Cloud Monitoring to monitor BI Engine metrics. I have a chart to measure the `Reservation Used Bytes`. The chart keeps changing values ranging from 30GB to 430MB, according to the chart. The time frame between days and weeks also does not change the measure chart. Why is the measuring changing throughout time to what appears to be from high to low and back to high? and, how can see how many bites have been utilized in total? Seems

Comment: Does this [link](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/monitoring-bigquery-reservations-and-slot-utilization-information_schema) help you?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a metric that is coupled to current usage, so it is expected to vary over time with increasing or decreasing values.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bi-engine-monitor#metrics

```
Reservation Used Bytes: Total capacity used in one Google Cloud project
```

If you need the total bytes you need to switch to this metric:

```
Reservation Total Bytes Total capacity allocated to one Google Cloud project
```

Comment: Reservation Total Bytes this gives me the total capacity, which i know what it is since i picked it. I just need to know how much of the total capacity has been consumed so far to know if we are close or not to capacity